# C# WebBrowser control with uninstalled IE (?)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, web-controls

I want to use WebBrowser control to load some localfile html page. I am aware that WebBrowser is just a wrapper around the InternetExplorer. As I remember Microsoft allowed users in Vista (?) to "uninstall" the InternetExplorer...

The question is:
Does WebBrowser runs smoothly with InternetExplorer uninstalled ? Does this uninstall do not affect DLL responsible for webpage rendering ?

I would apprecieate any input on this matter :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.  'Uninstalling' IE has no effect on this component.

Answer (score 5):

I know this has already been answered, but I think its worth to note:

The WebBrowser control provides a wrapper around the HTTP stack and the trident rendering engine.  This is independent of Internet Explorer, which essentially is a shell around this same set of technologies.  When you uninstall IE, you are not uninstalling Trident (MSHTML).